# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 +2 )$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 +2 )$, but is it more? Are these fields equal?
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)=\{a+b\sqrt2 |a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)=\{c+d(\sqrt2+2) |c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$
so we can find homomorphism which send $a +b \rightarrow c+2d +d$ where $a=c+2d$ and $b=d$. Is that correct thinking ? When they are equal they are also isomorphic.

Comment: They are equal, so yes, they are isomorphic.

Comment: Ok, is my thinking correct? Do I have to use homomorphism ?

Comment: Are you sure about your definitions of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+2)$ ? Especially $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$...?

Comment: Yes, of course to $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: If they are equal, then they are isomorphic. You don't need any homomorphism (and I'm not sure which homomorphism you had in mind. The one you tried to describe is unclear.)

Comment: That homomorphism: $f:(a+b\sqrt2) \rightarrow a+2b +b\sqrt2$. Is there another way to show that they are equal ?

Comment: @MrFrodo That is not a $\Bbb Q$ homomoprhism. An easy way to see that is that $(\sqrt 2)^2 - 2 = 0$ but $(2 + \sqrt 2)^2 - 2 \neq 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way here is to show that $\sqrt 2 = (\sqrt 2+2)-2 \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+2)$ and $\sqrt 2+2 \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ - which is trivial.

From the first we get $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) \subseteq \mathbb Q(2+\sqrt 2)$ and from the second we get the reverse inclusion.

The two fields are therefore equal and therefore isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** You can write $S_1=\{c+d(\sqrt{2}+2): c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ as  $S_2=\{(c+2d)+d(\sqrt{2}): c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Logically you don't need to find any isomorphism. All you need to know is that as sets $S_1=S_2$. Then since they are both subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ they obviously have the same inherent field structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should have seen that there is an equivalent characterization of $k(S)$ where $k$ is a field, and $S$ is a subset (or element) of a larger field $\Omega$. The definition you’ve apparently seen is “the set of all rational expressions in $S$, with coefficients in $k$”. But you can also define $k(S)$ as the intersection of all subfields of $\Omega$ that contain $k$ and $S$, or in other words, the smallest subfield of $\Omega$ that contains $k$ and $S$. The equivalence of these two definitions is not hard to prove.

With this latter definition it needs no argument whatever to see that if $\lambda\in\Bbb Q$, then $\Bbb Q(s)=\Bbb Q(s+\lambda)$.